# PHP - solarium with composer and Silex

Tags: php, silex, solarium

I've installed solarium with composer using below commands in ubuntu:

```
php composer.phar require solarium/solarium
```

I've also used silex micro framework. After installing solarium, when I tried to run sample php file in examples folder, I got error

```
"Fatal error: Class 'Solarium\Client' not found in  
/api/vendor/solarium/solarium/examples/1.1-check-solarium-and-ping.php on line 7"
```

How to get this work as expected?
I want to use both silex and solarium in a project.

Comment: did you include the /vendor/autoload.php file?

Comment: In that case you should debug where the Solarium/Client is defined and see composer generated autoload files in /vendor/composer whether this class is present. Nothing much we can help you with here.

Comment: Maybe it's because solarium use PSR-0 autoloader which is deprecated. You need proper configuration to fit PSR-4 autlooad. You can also use solarium autloader and include it in your project

Comment: There is no namespace 'Solarium' added at autoload_namespaces.php. Now i've added "'Solarium\\' => array($vendorDir . '/solarium/solarium/library'),". Now it is working fine.